# How to solve error on add ADT field in Delphi Firedac?

Tags: database, delphi, firedac

I'm using Delphi Community (10.2) and i have getting an error when adding an ADT field on Firedac `TFDQuery` by fields Editor. After added a ADT field, the subfields are added, but id raised an exception:

> "Field [subfield] not found"

In my `TFDQuery`, the SQL text is like: `"SELECT TABLE FROM TABLE"`.
I can't found any explanation about this error.

ps: dispite of erros is raised, the "subfield" works fine. Can be a BUG on Firedac?

Comment: Unless someone recognises this error scenario, your best way of diagnosing it is to set up your FQuery entirely in code, in other words, not using IDE editors such as the Fields editor at all. Then, if you still get the error, it should be trivial to find out where it occurs, but if you don't get it, the likelihood is that there is a problem in the FDac design-time code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that can be a problem in FireDac design-time code, like @MartynA says. However, one way to avoid the error is to set the `TFDQuery.ObjectView` property to `false` ([Displaying_ADT](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Displaying_ADT_and_Array_Fields)),  and, in this way, the sub-fields present in the ADT field will be persistent fields. To do it, you must first add the ADT field, then set `TFDQuery.ObjectView` to `false` and then add the ADT sub-fields in the `TFDQuery`.